# Client VPN Connection to Route 53 Private Hosted Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I have one privately hosted zone in my vpc using Route 53. I also have one client vpn connection to that vpc, which is functioning normally.
I want the client to get access to my website hosted using private zone in private subnet through their browser when they are connected to the VPN Client.

I have enabled "DNS Configuration" in the Client VPN Settings. But my client is not able to access the hostname of the webitse hosted in the private hosted zone. Though they are able to access the website using client vpn connection but by using ip address. I want them to access it using hostname.
I have tried defining the DNS ip in client vpn settings as

1. AWS Provided DNS (VPC CIDR + 2)
2. 2.Route 53 inbound endpoint ips.
   Both did not work. Help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guide, it might be useful for you, but as far as I understand you need to use direct connect or AWS VPN. Cause even if your client is inside the VPC by your custom VPN it still does not use the same DNS resolver  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route53-resolve-with-inbound-endpoint/

Comment: I am using AWS VPN only

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem 5 minutes ago:

1. i'm using ubuntu 22.04, the aws vpn client doesnt work very well

So:

1. I updated the aws client vpn config: Enable DNS servers, 10.0.0.2 (the default vpn server ip = vpn cidr + 2)
2. in my computer:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

i had something like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53

options edns0 trust-ad
search local
```

and then i updated to this:

```
search yourdnsexample.com
nameserver 10.0.0.2

nameserver 127.0.0.53

options edns0 trust-ad
search local
```

now for testing it i connected the vpn and tried with the next commands:

```
ping yourdnsexample.com
```

```
dig yourdnsexample.com A @10.0.0.2
```

```
dig yourdnsexample.com
```

i hope it helps someone